# Does the "get" method in Maps with defaults in Scala memoize?

Tags: scala, dictionary, scala-collections, memoization

Poking around Map.withDefault, I couldn't figure out where "get" is defined.  Although default seems to pretty clearly not memoize[1](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.9.2/src/library/scala/collection/Map.scala#L51), it seems like some implementations of "get" could memoize behind the scenes.

Basically, what I want to know is, if I have a computation that I want to only have to do once, will a map with a default do it many times, or only once?

Comment: What's the point of memozing a Map? Maps are used for memoizing other things; they're memoized almost by definition

Comment: Imagine a world where you start a map with a function, and now the map can be treated exactly like that function, except memoized.
  
private val underlying = MemoMap[Int, Int]((int: Int) => expensiveComputation(int))  
def fn(key: Int): Int = underlying(key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a problem. I've been doing a very similar trick for a long time.

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def someFunction ( s : String ) = {
  println("someFunction called")
  s.size
}
val someFunctionMemoized : String => Int
  = new collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int] {
      override def default ( key : String )
        = {
          val value = someFunction(key)
          update(key, value)
          value
        }
    }

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

someFunction: (s: String)Int
someFunctionMemoized: String => Int = Map()

scala> someFunctionMemoized("abc")
someFunction called
res0: Int = 3

scala> someFunctionMemoized("abc")
res1: Int = 3
```

Comment: Or `override def apply(x: String) = getOrElseUpdate(x, someFunction(x))`

Answer (score 1):

Immediately after asking the question, realized I could just check in the repl with a mutator embedded in my function.

```
scala> val map = new Map.WithDefault[String, String](Map(), {string => { println(string); string } } )
map: Map.WithDefault[String,String] = Map()

scala> map("key")
key
res5: String = key

scala> map("key")
key
res6: String = key

scala> import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.collection.mutable

scala> val mmap = new mutable.Map.WithDefault[String, String](mutable.Map(), {string => { println(string); string } } )
mmap: scala.collection.mutable.Map.WithDefault[String,String] = Map()

scala> mmap("key")
key
res7: String = key

scala> mmap("key")
key
res8: String = key
```

So the answer is: nope.  Roll your own.

Comment: … or use Scalaz. See memoization in [this cheat sheet](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=scalaz%20cheat%20sheet&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Farosien%2Fscalaz-base-talk-201208%2Fraw%2Fmaster%2Fscalaz-cheatsheet.pdf&ei=voNTUN60EOeM4gTq-oCAAQ&usg=AFQjCNGSJxAcQwW7gfsSdhHRoTVDieR1hg) for intance